# Disable right click menu of JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I want to disable the right click menu of JFreeChart.

I tried `chartPanel.setPopupMenu(null)`, but it didn't work.

[image: Right Click Menu]

Comment: You may be changing the wrong `ChartPanel`. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The following example creates a simple XYPlot with "panel.setPopupMenu( null )" disabling the popup Menu.
`
public class DisableChartPopupMenu extends ApplicationFrame {

```
public DisableChartPopupMenu(String title) {
    super(title);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    (new DisableChartPopupMenu("example")).createChartNoPopupMenu();
}

public void createChartNoPopupMenu(){
    final XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Series 1");
    series1.add(10.0, 12353.3);
    series1.add(20.0, 13734.4);
    series1.add(30.0, 14525.3);
    series1.add(40.0, 13984.3);
    final XYSeriesCollection collection = new XYSeriesCollection();
    collection.addSeries(series1);
    final XYItemRenderer renderer1 = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    final NumberAxis rangeAxis1 = new NumberAxis("Range 1");
    final XYPlot subplot1 = new XYPlot( collection, null, rangeAxis1, renderer1);
    final CombinedDomainXYPlot plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(new NumberAxis("Domain"));
    plot.add(subplot1, 1);
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(" Demo", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
    final ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart, true, true, true, false, true);
    panel.setPopupMenu( null );
    setContentPane(panel); pack(); setVisible(true);
}
```

}
`